# How to disable oncontextmenu while rightclick dragging?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I code a webgame and I need to disable the oncontextmenu (for a rightclick mousemove issue).

On Chrome and Opera (at least), the oncontextmenu appears when you right click, mouve the mouse and release rightclick,  even if you use:

```
<body oncontextmenu="return false;">
```

(this only disable immobile rightclick)

How to disable it all?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This CSS will disable the immobile right clicks from occuring

```
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  /* Chrome all / Safari all */
  -moz-user-select: none;
  /* Firefox all */
  -ms-user-select: none;
  /* IE 10+ */
  user-select: none;
```

This JS will disable them all

```
document.addEventListener('contextmenu', event => event.preventDefault());
```

Comment: So you already have this code but you're able to right click inside your element? Is it a flash game or java applet?

Comment: even if you only display a simple body, when you right click, move and release, a contextmenu pop out in chrome browser, i just try. i join a fiddle

Comment: Hey you were right, sorry this disabled long touches from displaying the context menu, let me add the exact javascript fix

Comment: How is that JS effectively any different than the OPs `oncontextmenu=return false`?

Comment: fiddle contextmenu seems always active :p, i'll try your code thank you

Comment: Scott Marcus, I dont know, I'm a very beginner, but this solved the problem.

Comment: @ScottMarcus This JS applies to the entire document, and in case something weird happens where an object gets DOM'd up out of the body. I think the big thing here is in case the body tag is styled to not cover the entire document the `document.addEventListener` will still catch it

Comment: Well, that doesn't really explain anything.